# Unregister on new Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the new google cloud messaging

```
(GoogleCloudMessaging gcm =
           GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance (context);)
```

I am following this example, which is very good and works perfectly:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2

With this example I can register in the GCM, but I tried unsuccessfully to unregister.

in the documentation indicates that you should use the following intent:

```
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER
```

And use it as follows:

```
 Intent unregIntent = new Intent ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
     unregIntent.putExtra ("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast (this, 0, new Intent (), 0));
     StartService (unregIntent);
```

not working ...

As I said, the register works fine, but do not know how to unregister.

I have to do more than the intent? What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any help

Thanks and regards

Comment: very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` class, you don't need to use the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER` intent. Simply use [GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#unregister%28%29).

> **public void unregister ()**
>
> Unregister the application. Calling unregister() stops any messages from the server. This is a blocking call—you shouldn't call it from the UI thread. You should rarely (if ever) need to call this method. Not only is it expensive in terms of resources, but it invalidates your registration ID, which should never change unnecessarily. A better approach is to simply have your server stop sending messages. Only use unregister if you want your application to stop using GCM permanently, or you have a compelling reason to recycle your registration ID.
>   Throws
>   IOException     if we can't connect to server to unregister.

Comment: can i call this at a time the app is unistalled? if yes how?

Comment: @Fahim No, there's no way to run logic when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: @Fahim You don't need to unregister your device when you app is uninstalled. GCM does it for you itself, as mentioned in this SO answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28057615/3913366 .

Answer (score 1):

Unregistration may take up to 5 minutes to propagate.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg-why

Comment: While this link may answer the posted question, you better include some excerpts out of it, possibly with some code snippets, since the page might not be available in the future.

Comment: Welcome to the future.

Answer (score 0):

### Old Way (Deprecated):

**public synchronized void [unregister()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#unregister())**

### New Way (Instead use):

```
InstanceID.deleteToken();
```

or

```
InstanceID.deleteInstanceID();
```

> Unregister the application. Calling unregister() stops any messages
> from the server. This is a blocking call—you shouldn't call it from
> the UI thread. You should rarely (if ever) need to call this method.
> Not only is it expensive in terms of resources, but it invalidates all
> your registration IDs returned from register() or subscribe(). This
> should not be done unnecessarily. A better approach is to simply have
> your server stop sending messages.