# Appcelerator Titanium run code on uninstall (android)

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator

Pretty much the title. I have the app register the device to receive push notifications when it runs, I need to unregister the device when it uninstalls. How to?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you write about uninstall in the meaning of deleting the app from the device?

Unregistering from GCM on the device-side may take several minutes and therefor probably can not be done on uninstall, [see answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722504/unregister-on-new-google-cloud-messaging).

Your server should just stop sending push notifications. If he tries GCM returns an NotRegistered-error, [see the docs here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#response).

If you're using Appcelerator services for notifications then the error comes from their servers.